# Drop highest and lowest of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting

right now I have a project dealing with fractions. The fractions need to be sorted and the highest and lowest are dropped, and then the middle fractions are added together. I have created the array, and done the sort. I am stuck as to how to drop the highest and lowest. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] fractions = {(6/7),(2/4),(3/4),(3/18),(1/8),(10/20),(2/6)};
}
public static void selectionSort (int... arr)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, smallest = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (i = 0;i<arr.length - 1;i++)
    {
        smallest = i;
        for (j = 1; j<arr.length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j]<arr[smallest])
                smallest = j;
        }
        temp = arr[smallest];
        arr[smallest] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;

    }

    //Drop highest and lowest here
}
}
```

Comment: Your sort method takes in `int` array even though you are working with `double`?

Comment: Create another array and copy it from the second element to the last one - 1

Comment: I guess it does, its not getting any errors right now because of int or double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you have to add decimal points to either the denominator or numerator in your array initialization to get an array that is not full of `0`'s (That way you are not doing integer math). Or simply add a `d` at the end of your integer math (`6/7d`).

Next you can sort using `Arrays.sort` (or continue using your custom sort method) and you can get a sub array using `Arrays.copyOfRange`. This is very handy since you can give it a starting index and an ending index. Something like this should do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] fractions = {(6./7),(2./4),(3./4),(3./18),(1./8),(10./20),(2./6)}; //Add decimal points
    Arrays.sort(fractions); //Sort your array
    double[] removeLowestAndHighest = Arrays.copyOfRange(fractions, 1, fractions.length-1); //returns new array with first and last element removed.    
}
```

Comment: Okay, I was wondering why I was getting all 0.0's when I printed the array, thanks for the help.

Comment: I prefer ``1/3d`` over ``1./3`` or ``1/3.``, it's clearer and works similar for ``float``s.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the solution to include this alternate as well.

Comment: Just curious, does d mean double?

Comment: @homidhomi4 yes. The `d` is how you declare a `double`. You could also do something like `(double) 1/ 3`

Comment: Wow! Thank you. In class we learned about selection sort, but doing Arrays.sort is so much easier! I knew about the Arrays.toString to print my array but not the sort. That makes everything so much easier! Thanks!!!!

Comment: @homidhomi4 yup no worries. I would check out all the other `Arrays` methods. There is even one for binary search. Very handy stuff in deed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use List, then u can simple use .remove(0), .remove(size-1)

Comment: Is that a method? So how would I call it. Would I just do my arrayname.list?

Comment: something like this: 
ArrayList array;
        array = new ArrayList();
        array.add("item");
        array.remove(0);

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a new array that is 2 smaller than the orriginal.
int[] newArr = new int[arr.length-2];  
// Iterate through the old array, skipping the first and last elements.
for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
{
    newArr[i] = arr[i+1];
}
```